# Difference between dates with one date column in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have the below query:

```
SELECT transaction_date,tanks.name,stations.name,products.name,tank_sales 
FROM tanks_product_movement LEFT JOIN stations ON station_id=stations.id 
LEFT JOIN products ON product_id=products.id LEFT JOIN tanks ON 
tank_id=tanks.id WHERE products.name='AGO'
AND stations.name='CG-Station'
```

i want to know the difference in sales between two days i.e sales difference between 2019-04-01 and 2019-04-02 ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr7t6.png)

Comment: Please _delete_ the external image link, and instead include a _text_ table, directly in your question, which shows us the output you actually want to have here.

Comment: 2019-04-01 AGOTank2 CG-Kasavubu Station AGO
2019-04-02 AGOTank2 CG-Kasavubu Station AGO
2019-04-03 AGOTank2 CG-Kasavubu Station AGO
2019-04-04 AGOTank2 CG-Kasavubu Station AGO
2019-04-05 AGOTank2 CG-Kasavubu Station AGO
2019-04-06 AGOTank2 CG-Kasavubu Station AGO
2019-04-07 AGOTank2 CG-Kasavubu Station AGO
2019-04-08 AGOTank2 CG-Kasavubu Station AGO
2019-04-09 AGOTank2 CG-Kasavubu Station AGO
2019-04-09 AGOTank2 CG-Kasavubu Station AGO
2019-04-10 AGOTank2 CG-Kasavubu Station AGO

Comment: sent the plain text with output form 1st to 10th, now is it possible to get the sales difference between the dates and display on another column i.e sales difference between 2019-04-01 and 2019-04-01 next 2019-04-02 and 2019-04-03.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these two dates would occur only once in the respective table, you could use pivoting logic here:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN transaction_date = '2019-04-02' THEN tank_sales END) -
    MAX(CASE WHEN transaction_date = '2019-04-01' THEN tank_sales END) AS sales_diff
FROM tanks_product_movement tpm
LEFT JOIN stations s
    ON tpm.station_id = s.id 
LEFT JOIN products p
    ON tpm.products_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN tanks t
    ON tank_id = t.id
WHERE
    p.name = 'AGO' AND
    s.name = 'CG-Station';
```

To find the difference between today and yesterday's sales use:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN transaction_date = CURDATE() THEN tank_sales END) -
    MAX(CASE WHEN transaction_date = SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1) THEN tank_sales END)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What if i have dates from 2019-04-01 to 2019-04-30 and i want the difference between sales based on the current and previous date.

Comment: Thank you Tim, tried to run the above select statement to get the difference in sales between the dates but output is blank

Comment: Hi Tim, i have added the image of the output on my question, is it possible to have a difference column to the output to show sales difference between days